# Color correct to compensate for low blue

Tags: color-correction, color, color-grading, bluescreen

Everytime I create a video,it looks good in a normal screen but considering half of the people have the low blue light effect enabled, I would like to balance somehow the colors of my videos to counter the effect of blue light, since otherwise my videos look orange.

Comment: Hi Daniel - a screen shot of the problem would really help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very certain that I understand your question, but if you want to shift the color-grade of your image away from the orange, you can use the temperature to shift it towards blue, effectively making your image less orange. The temperature setting is available in any popular grading-tool, such as lumetri, resolve or nuke.

Another option might be to actually grade your footage using a monitor that is tuned to the blue-reduced setting. I would like to add though, that you will likely lose some brightness, since most blue-reduction methods simply take away from the value of the blue-channel. So additionally taking away from the orange-channel to compensate will likely darken your image. Also also: People who watch movies on blue-reduced monitors should not be your main focus when grading. Professional studios often grade on 10-bit, calibrated monitors that will look quite different from the average consumer-display. We still grade for the calibrated monitor though, to ensure the best experience on average for most the people who consume the product.

Comment: That "also also" bit is key. Color grade, frame for safe area, mix, loudness correct, etc. for your reference environment, check in a likely real world scenario, and adjust for the worst problems. Repeat as necessary. Back in the early days of stereo audio, when mono TVs with small, tinny drivers were still common, audio would be mixed on the studio reference monitors and then checked with the TV in the break room.

Comment: I guess if you *knew* that most of your audience was going to see the video with their screens tinted orange, then the logical thing to do would be to adjust for that. The challenge would be making it look ok for the rest of the audience. Also, the tinny speakers on TVs were fantastic when compared to the tinny speaker on a phone.